# I always wonder about meaning of like [, thisArg] things

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I study Javascript code in MDN, but I don't understand what's the meaning of [, thisArg] things...
for example,

```
arr.map(callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])
```

in this case, I know about there needs to be have callback Function. but what's that in the square brackets? why they need comma in case of there's nothing in front of?

Comment: It's their notation to show that those arguments are optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that whatever is in the brackets is an optional argument. If you do use an additional optional argument, you need a comma to separate it from the previous argument.

The notation

```
arr.map(callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])
```

perhaps more easily read as

```
arr.map(
  callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])
  [, thisArg]
)
```

means that the callback can accept 1, 2, or 3 arguments, and that `.map` accepts the callback as the first argument, and can optionally accept a second argument (the `thisArg`) as well.

As Kaiido notes, in the specific case of `Array.prototype.map`, the `currentValue` is actually optional as well, it's just extremely odd to use `.map` without using *any* of the arguments:

```js
const arr = [3, 4];
const newArr = arr.map(() => 999);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: oh, then [, this means just an option in this bracket] right?

Comment: It means that what is inside the bracket is an optional argument.

Comment: But to be fair, even `currentValue` can be optional here... We are the author of `callback`... Not sure why they did set these square brackets... The ones for `thisArg` make sense though.